# Spark Streaming concurrent updates on ElasticSearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, concurrency

I am playing with Spark and ElasticSearch upserting elements in my index. In particular Spark reads JSON messages from Kafka, and index them on ES. If the message already exists they need to get one of the element, incrementing a counter, updating it and send it to kafka for other operations.

Since my cluster has multiple workers and potentially they could write the same element I am wondering if ElasticSearch might suffer from concurrency problem. And if ES might be ideal for this case.

If not, which DB might be good for this kind of operation.

What if Another Spark module might update the same element decrementing the counter when that id come back from processing decrementing the field counter. Is there a chance of concurrency problem

Comment: is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304316/how-to-upsert-or-partial-updates-with-script-documents-in-elasticsearch-with-spa

Comment: @salvob Can you please explain why I shouldn't close this question as a duplicate for the linked one that you have also posted ?

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your interest. 
Well, it's a different question. That one is specific to code "how do you do an update in spark streaming/ What's the API called". 
This one is more theoretical: "Will I have problems of concurrency if I use SparkStreaming with ElasticSearch?".  What happens if Spark jobs try to modify the same resource?

Comment: Basically this question is about the conflicts. Does ES have lots of conflicts using it with Spark/Spark-Streaming/Structured-Streaming ?