# How to upsert or partial updates with script documents in ElasticSearch with Spark?

Tags: python, scala, elasticsearch, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a pseudocode in python that reads from a Kafka stream and upsert documents in Elasticsearch (incrementing a counter `view` if the document exists already.

```
for message in consumer:

    msg = json.loads(message.value)
    print(msg)
    index = INDEX_NAME
    es_id = msg["id"]
    script = {"script":"ctx._source.view+=1","upsert" : msg}
    es.update(index=index, doc_type="test", id=es_id, body=script)
```

Since I want to use it in a distributed environment, I am using Spark Structured Streaming

```
df.writeStream \
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
.queryName("ESquery")\
.option("es.resource","credentials/url") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start()
```

or SparkStreaming in scala that reads from KafkaStream:

```
// Initializing Spark Streaming Context and kafka stream
sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
[...] 
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
    )

[...]
val urls = messages.map(record => JsonParser.parse(record.value()).values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
urls.saveToEs("credentials/credential")
```

`.saveToEs(...)` is the API of `elastic-hadoop.jar` documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html). Unfortunately [this repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) is not really well documented. So I cannot understand where I can put the script command.

Is there anyone can help me? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it by setting write mode "update" ( or upsert) and passing your script as "script" (depends on ES version).

```
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id", "es.write.operation" -> "update","es.update.script.inline" -> "your script" , ))
```

Probably you want to use "upsert"

There are some good [unit tests in cascading integration](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/blob/master/cascading/src/itest/java/org/elasticsearch/hadoop/integration/cascading/AbstractCascadingLocalJsonSaveTest.java#L141) in same library; These settings should be good for spark as both uses same writer.

I suggest to read unit tests to pick correct settings for your ES version.