# how can sparksql update to elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I want to use `sparksql` to only update one of the fields in the `ElasticSearch`. But it covers it.
Can anyone please explain how can it be done?

Below is my code:

```
import com.bjvca.utils.PVConstant
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

object DF2ESTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = conf...

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val person = sc.textFile("F:\\mrdata\\person\\input\\person.txt")
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map(p => Person(p(0), p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))  //first write
      // .map(p => Person(p(0),p(0)))                 //want to update name
      .toDF()

    person.saveToEs("person/person", Map("es.mapping.id" -> "id"))

  }
}

case class Person(id: String, name: String, age: Int)
//case class Person(id:String,name: String)
```

**first:write data to `elasticsearch`.
second: i want update only name to es,but it covers old data than age is disap**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304316/how-to-upsert-or-partial-updates-with-script-documents-in-elasticsearch-with-spa/47317727#47317727

Comment: Formatted content